# SQL Server - Sumar Por condiciones Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

**¡Hola Amigos, un Jr por estos lados!**

Vengo por acá porque me encantaría pedirles asesoramiento en relación a como sumar/restar por condiciones dentro de una tabla, ej:

```
Dia Mes Año Producto Sucursal Coste  TipodeFactura
-----------------------------------------------------
2    1  2022 Lápiz    0002      1.00      A
2    1  2022 Pendrive 0002      2.00      A
2    1  2022 Agua     0002      5.00      B
```

Se supone que si sumamos los campos Daría algo así

```
Dia Mes Año Producto Sucursal Coste    Factura    TipodeFactura   TotalFacturacion
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2    1  2022 Lápiz    0002      1.00     053            A                8.00
2    1  2022 Pendrive 0002      2.00     053            A                8.00
2    1  2022 Agua     0002      5.00     053            B                8.00
```

EL problema es que las facturas A son para compras siendo positivos, y B para retornos de productos siendo Negativos.

El resultado esperado sería algo como:

```
Dia Mes Año Producto Sucursal Coste    Factura    TipodeFactura TotalFacturacion CantidadComprada
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2    1  2022 Lápiz    0002      1.00     053            A           3.00               2
2    1  2022 Pendrive 0002      2.00     053            A           3.00               2
```

Mis códigos son los siguientes :

```
SELECT 
    CodUbic,
    DAY(FechaE) AS Dia_Transaccion, 
    MONTH(FechaE) AS Mes, 
    YEAR(FechaE) AS Ano, 
    Descrip1 AS ProductoNombre, 
    CodItem, 
    TotalItem, 
    NumeroD AS Factura
INTO #ClientesProductos
FROM 
    dbo.-
WHERE 
   TipoFac IN ('A','B') AND 
   YEAR(FechaE) IN(2021,2022) 
GROUP BY 
   DAY(FechaE),
   MONTH(FechaE), 
  YEAR(FechaE),
  CodUbic, 
  TipoFac,
  Descrip1, 
  CodItem, 
  TotalItem, 
  NumeroD
```

Acá realizo un Inner

```
SELECT Cantidad AS Cant_$, Dia AS Dia_Transaccion, Mes AS Mes_Transacción, Ano AS Años_Transacción, CodUbic, NumeroD
INTO ProductosAA
FROM PruebaProducto
WHERE Tipofac = 'A'

SELECT -(Cantidad) AS Cant_$_Devoluciones, Dia AS Dia_Transaccion, Mes AS Mes_Transacción, Ano AS Años_Transacción, CodUbic, NumeroD
INTO ProductosBB
FROM PruebaProducto
WHERE Tipofac = 'B'
```

Y con esta las unifico

```
SELECT (A.Cant_$ + B.Cant_$_Devoluciones) AS Total_Productos, A.Dia_Transaccion, A.Mes_Transacción, A.Años_Transacción, A.CodUbic
INTO PRUEBAS
FROM
    ProductosAA AS A
INNER JOIN ProductosBB AS B 
ON A.CodUbic = B.CodUbic
AND A.Mes_Transacción = B.Mes_Transacción
AND A.Años_Transacción = B.Años_Transacción
ORDER BY A.Mes_Transacción
```

Mi objetivo es obtener una tabla como la mostrada arriba, pero, no soy capaz de contar el número de objetivos dada la factura y discernir con los A y no con los B, y menos del total de facturación.

Consulté con unos colegas y me comentaron de esta fórmula:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN monto ELSE -monto END) AS Total_Facturación
```

Pero esta me das es un total y yo lo necesito por Factura.

Y esta otra

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER ( partition by Descrip order by NumeroD) + DENSE_RANK() OVER (partition by Descrip order by NumeroD desc) -1 as VecesComprado
```

Pero lo que hace es contar la cantidad de veces que el cliente compró y no en sí de los productos llevados

Answer (score 0):

Estás creando demasiadas tablas y no es necesario porque todo eso se puede hacer en memoria. Lo que te dieron los colegas es un buen inicio, pero necesitas la clausula `PARTITION BY`.

Desgraciadamente, los códigos que muestras no siguen una lógica porque van cambiando los nombres de las columnas y estructura de las tablas. Sin embargo, dejo este ejemplo de como podrías acercarte más a tu respuesta.

La función `OVER()` permite tener totales en la misma fila. `PARTITION BY` funciona de forma similar a como funcionaría `GROUP BY` en un agregado normal.

```
SELECT 
    DAY(FechaE) AS Dia_Transaccion, 
    MONTH(FechaE) AS Mes, 
    YEAR(FechaE) AS Ano, 
    Descrip1 AS ProductoNombre, 
    CodUbic AS Sucursal,
    NumeroD AS Factura,
    TipoFac AS TipodeFactura, 
    SUM( IIF( TipoFac = 'A', TotalItem, -TotalItem)) OVER( PARTITION BY NumeroD) AS TotalFactura
FROM 
    dbo.-
WHERE 
   TipoFac IN ('A','B') AND 
   YEAR(FechaE) IN(2021,2022);
```